# Why did SpringBoot move away from 'spring.factories' to 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports'?

Tags: spring-boot

After SpringBoot 3.x, the official seems to have removed the `spring.factories` configuration file and replaced it with `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure. AutoConfiguration.importations`. I want to know the reason for this?

I found this passage in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29698:

> **Using `spring.factories` to find auto-configuration classes is causing problems with our native work**. We initially used it because the code was already available, but we want to offer an alternative in 2.7 and stop using spring.factories for auto-configuration in 3.0.

What the term "problems" refers to in this context. I have attempted to find answers in the documentation or issues, but it seems there isn't a very clear explanation of the necessity of adopting this new approach. Can someone provide insights into this issue for me?

Comment: I have noticed the obvious advantage of import files over spring-factories: now it is possible to discover all `spring-boot` auto-configurations via examining the classpath (cmd+shift+o in IntelliJ) of application/project, in my case that is just 5 files vs 40 files, which may potentially contain auto-configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring.factories` was introduced for earlier versions of **Spring Boot** and didn't align well with the framework's evolving design principles. The new approach is part of a broader effort to simplify Spring Boot's configuration mechanisms, resulting in a cleaner and more intuitive experience for developers.

To start with, `spring.factories` was a convention-based mechanism, lacking explicit configuration and potentially leading to confusion and unintended side effects. The new approach using `@AutoConfiguration` with the `imports` attribute and dedicated annotation-based conditions provides a more transparent and maintainable way to declare auto-configuration.

`spring.factories` offered limited control over the loading order and conditional behavior of auto-configurations. The configurations were loaded in the sequence in which they were declared in spring.factories. The new approach allows finer-grained control through annotations like @ConditionalOnClass, @ConditionalOnBean, and custom conditions, enabling more flexible and predictable auto-configuration.

Moreover, testing **auto-configuration**s using `spring.factories` was cumbersome and required modifying the file itself. The new approach makes testing easier by relying on annotations and Spring's bean lifecycle, enhancing maintainability and testability of auto-configuration logic.

Alternatively, Spring boot team could have enhanced existing mechanism of `spring.factories` rather than implementing new conventions. But I guess that was done to support both mechanisms intermittently when it was first introduced in `Spring Boot v2.7.x`. Support for it is completely removed starting from `Spring Boot v3`

Here is some official explanation of this change (not enough though): https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29872

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Can I take the view that the whole point is to change SPI from "manual" mode to "automatic" mode based on the @AutoConfiguration + Annotation Processor, and that the format or file name change is just an add-on?